# How to check availability of each directoriy (directory tree) in a file path. Unix/Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, increment

Given a text file with paths (on each line a new path).
Need to create directories from paths. This is done easily like `mkdir -p is/isapp/ip/ipapp`. Then `chgrp group1 is/isapp/ip/ipapp`. But the problem is that access only changes for the final `ipapp` directory. And you need to change access for all newly created directories, while not changing access for directories that already existed before the `mkdir -p` command. Therefore, you need to check which directories already exist and change permissions only for newly created directories. Below I tried to split the path from file and gradually increase it until the moment when the search does not find the directory. And then `chgrp -R` with the path to the directory that was not found. Below are my code sketches. I would be grateful for any help.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1 /(file with paths(in each line new path))
while read LINE; do
IFS='/' read -ra my_array <<< "$my_string"
  if ! [ -d "${my_array[0]}" ]; then
  mkdir -p "${my_array[0]}"
  else -d "${my_array[0]}"/"${my_array[@]}"
done
fi
```

Comment: well, that's something, but where do you use `FILE`? What is with `else -d` ? Best to run this thru https://shellcheck.net and fix all errors that it highlights and then update your Q. It will avoid playing "20 questions' if you include some sample data that should be processed. Do you want to include error checking? Include bad data then. `man mkdir` and read about the `-m` option. It may be able to help. Finally, it seems that you'll need a 2nd inner loop to process each segment of `/path/to/dir` (if I understand your Q correctly). Good luck!

Comment: where is `$my_string` coming from? Best to read about `while read rec ; do .... cmds ; done < inputFile` . Please update your Q and avoid as much as possible replying in comments. Good luck.

Comment: Please post example input file and example output directory/file layout with groups. You can "split the path from file" with `basename` and `dirname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:   (basically for each directory level try to cd up, and if you can't create the directory with the proper permissions).

```
#!/bin/bash
MODE=u+rw
ROOT=$(pwd)
while read PATH; do
        IFS='/' read -r -a dirs <<< "${PATH}"
        for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
             [ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}" -m ${MODE} || exit 1
             cd "${dir}"
        done
        cd "${ROOT}"
done
```

Note: this is reading from stdin (so you would have to pipe your file into the script), or alternatively add `< ${FILE}` right after the `done` to pipe it in manually).   The quotes around the `"${dir}"` and `"${dirs[@]}"` are required in case there are any whitespace characters in the filenames.

The `exit 1` saves you in case the `mkdir` fails (say there's a file with the name of the directory you want to create).

Comment: This code works fine! Thanks for your help! But I need to change the permissions for the group (now this is done with 'chgrp group1 is/isapp/ip/ipapp'). For example path from file with paths - 'is/isapp/al/prog1'. But i already have in Linux this directories - is/isapp. I should create al and prog1 directories and set their group rights like chgrp group1 only for them and don't touch any rights and group rights already existing directories.

Comment: I tried replacing '[ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}" -m ${MODE} || exit 1' with a new one - '[ -d "${dir}" ] || mkdir "${dir}" || sudo chgrp group1 "${dir}" || exit 1' but it didn’t works. I am new to bash, so I don’t fully understand how this can be implemented. I would really appreciate for help with this issue.

Comment: the `||` is a short-circuit or operator.   That is, if you have `a || b`, it will first run `a`.  If `a` returns success, it doesn't bother running `b`.   So in your case, you did `[ -d "${dir} ] || mkdir ${dir} || sudo chgrp group1 "${dir}" || exit 1`.   Notice that the directory does not exist (so your first condition fails).  It then tries the second condition, which is the `mkdir`, which passes, and so it doesn't bother with the rhs of the next `||` operator.   You likely want to do this:   `[ -d "${dir}" ] || ( mkdir "${dir} && sudo chgrp group1 "${dir}" ) || exit 1`

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake in the description with the format of the paths that are stored in the file (Not like {is/isapp/al}, but like this {/home/username/is/isapp/al} (full path). Now when I run the script, a directory is created like {/home/username/is/isapp/al} but i don't need {home} and {username} ditectories. I tried adding {~/} in different places but it didn't help. Maybe you can help with this issue? And I apologize for bothering you again

Comment: You can remove a prefix off the front of each element of a bash array simply enough:  `dir=( "${dir[@]##/home/username/} )` See [here](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/90d6fe30fc247ef110a1) for string manipulations that can be done in bash.